# Dynamically format multiple columns (round to two decimal places)

Tags: mdx

I am new to MDX, but from what I've read, the way to format the output for a number column is to modify the `FORMAT` property on the cube in which it's defined. I don't have access to do that, so I was looking for a way to do it dynamically in the query, and I found [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7d796efe-8a91-4522-9323-a982e82abfbe/dynamic-format-string-in-measurespossible?forum=sqlanalysisservices), which does the following:

```
with 
    cell calculation [Round2]
    for '[Measures].[MyNumber]'
    as [Measures].CurrentMember
    , format_string = "#,#0.00"
select 
    non empty {[Measures].[MyNumber]} on columns
    , non empty ([MyDim].[MyDescription].[MyDescription]) on rows
from 
    [Cube]
;
```

I've got this working. However, I have multiple columns that will need this same formatting applied. I've tried adding more columns in the `for` clause, like `for '[Measures].[MyNumber1], [Measures].[MyNumber2], ...'`, as well as other variants, but nothing is working except the "single-column syntax".

Questions:

1. Is there a way to apply formatting like this in a concise manner to
   multiple columns, without having to repeat the `cell calculation`
   syntax for every column needing the formatting?
2. Is there a better approach to dynamically format the columns
   (without modifying the properties defined in the Cube).

Comment: you can format in most clients to mdx - ssrs, excel etc

Comment: @whytheq Yes, that's true, but I'd like to apply the formatting consistently among all clients, so I'd rather include it in the query definition instead of relying on the client to implement it correctly. Thanks for the comment.